# Как заменить getState и getId(из Thread) при исп. Runnable?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я создавал потоки исп. `extends Thread`,  решил заменить его на `Runnable`. Но я использовал методы `getState` и `getI`d, которых в интерфейсе нет.
Просто не очень понимаю, как внутри JDK устроены потоки, т.е. если я использую `Thread thr = new Thread()`, а потом `thr.getState()`, то мне кажется что он покажет мне state не того что мне нужен потока?

Comment: А какой поток нужен?

Comment: @RomanC поток класса который реализует Runnable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно по классике делают так.
В классе, который имплементит `Runnable`, создают переменную `private Thread thread;`. Далее, в конструкторе этого же класса инициализируют ее вновь созданным потоком, передавая себя как параметр: `this.thread = new Thread(this);`. Создают `getter` для этой переменной: `public Thread getThread() { return thread; }`.
Можно тут же, в конструкторе, и запустить поток (если нужно): `thread.start();`. Или же потом, с помощью `getter`-a когда время придет... Так же, при помощи `getter`-a теперь можно доставать свойства и методы `Thread`-a.